# the meaning of "more or less"

Tags: phrase-meaning, idioms-in-context

> The meaning of ‘permission’ is strengthened to something like ‘strong recommendation’ **in more or less joking or offensive remarks** such as: *You can forget about your holiday. | If he doesn’t like it he can lump it. | This chicken is half-cooked. Take it back to the cook and tell him where he can put it.*

(from p.75 of <Meaning and the English Verb (3rd ed.)> by Geoffrey Leech)

Here, what's the exact meaning of "in more or less joking or offensive remarks"?
What's the difference between "in more or less joking or offensive remarks" and "in joking or offensive remarks"?

Comment: "more or less" joking simply means some jokes might be primarily good-natured humour, where others might be "barbed" (intending to be offensive / hurtful).

Comment: Since jokes and offensive language are somewhat (more or less) subjective, I can say "Oh, I was just joking. That wasn't offensive!" But if you think my language was vaguely (more or less) bad, you can now take a 'strong recommendation’ to object, even if the words were not black-and-white rude.

Comment: @FumbleFingers O.K. Then how do you think about the following interpretation?

"More" is interpreted as being corresponding to "joking", and having the meaning of, say, "in the eye of more plus side"(or "in the eye of more far distance"). On the other hand, "less" is interpreted as being corresponding to "offensive", and having the meaning of, say, "in the eye of less plus side"(or "in the eye of less far distance").

Comment: @FumbleFingers In this interpretation, "a more or less joking or offensive remark" is a remark which is not only a joke on the plus side, but also offensive words on the minus side, or it is a joke when seen in long-shot, but offensive words when seen in close-up.

Comment: @YosefBaskin O.K. Then how do you think about the following interpretation? "More" is interpreted as being corresponding to "joking", and having the meaning of, say, "in the eye of more plus side"(or "in the eye of more far distance"). On the other hand, "less" is interpreted as being corresponding to "offensive", and having the meaning of, say, "in the eye of less plus side"(or "in the eye of less far distance").

Comment: @YosefBaskin In this interpretation, "a more or less joking or offensive remark" is a remark which is not only a joke on the plus side, but also offensive words on the minus side, or it is a joke when seen in long-shot, but offensive words when seen in close-up.

Comment: Sorry, you misunderstood. "More or less" goes together to mean *approximately*. If I make $9.50 an hour or $11.25, I will say I make "more or less $10."

Comment: If I make a joke that is not friendly, you won't like it. Also, if I make an offensive remark, you won't like it. In both cases, you have more than "permission" to say "No good!", you have strong recommendation to say that.

Comment: @YosefBaskin O.K. Then, do you think as follows?

**You can forget about your holiday.**
: In some respects, this remark is more or less joking, but in other repects, it is more or less offensive.

**If he doesn’t like it he can lump it.**
: In some respects, this remark is more or less joking, but in other repects, it is more or less offensive.

**This chicken is half-cooked. Take it back to the cook and tell him where he can put it.**
: In some respects, this remark is more or less joking, but in other repects, it is more or less offensive.

Comment: You have it now. People hide criticism, bias, and anger behind humor: "I was only joking!" Even if they claim there joking to some extent (more or less), their message can hurt.

Comment: @YosefBaskin Many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

"*More or less*" idiomatically means that the associated statement is correct *within reason* or *within a reasonable margin*. For example, if someone did a quick, rough count of something and declared that there was "*more or less 100*" they might mean that there could be 99 (less) or 101 (more), but that 100 is a reasonably correct answer.

The phrase is often used beyond the scope of numeric matters, though. For example, you might hear that something is "*more or less true*" which means it is *mostly* true - perhaps a story based on truth but with a few embellishments.

Your example of "*more or less joking or offensive remarks*" is a little unusual, but I would understand it to mean remarks which are *mostly* joking; that is something which is intended to be funny but there may be some truth in it. One of the cited examples of "*This chicken is half-cooked. Take it back to the cook and tell him where he can put it*" is a euphemism which literally means you should tell the chef to insert the chicken up his anus. Obviously, this is a "joke", but there is still a truth in it - that the chicken isn't cooked and a complaint is warranted - so it is "more or less" a joke.

Comment: O.K. Then how do you think about the following interpretation? "More" is interpreted as being corresponding to "joking", and having the meaning of, say, "in the eye of more plus side"(or "in the eye of more far distance"). On the other hand, "less" is interpreted as being corresponding to "offensive", and having the meaning of, say, "in the eye of less plus side"(or "in the eye of less far distance").

Comment: In this interpretation, "a more or less joking or offensive remark" is a remark which is not only a joke on the plus side, but also offensive words on the minus side, or it is a joke when seen in long-shot, but offensive words when seen in close-up.

Comment: @gonjuyi you're reading too much into it. When it isn't used with something quantifiable, it just means "mostly". It's a phrase that has just extended beyond its original use. A similar phrase "give or take" remains exclusively used with estimated counts.

Comment: O.K. Then, do you think as follows?

**You can forget about your holiday.**
: In some respects, this remark is more or less joking, but in other repects, it is more or less offensive.

**If he doesn’t like it he can lump it.**
: In some respects, this remark is more or less joking, but in other repects, it is more or less offensive.

**This chicken is half-cooked. Take it back to the cook and tell him where he can put it.**
: In some respects, this remark is more or less joking, but in other repects, it is more or less offensive.